# Having problem to add favourite button on book details page where user can tap and change icon

Tags: flutter, provider

I have a book details page where I want to show a favourite button and a user will tap and the favourite button will change it's icon. But I am not finding any way to do this.
I am using providers for state management.

This is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './screens/home_screen.dart';
import './providers/book_list_provider.dart';
import './screens/book_detail_screen.dart';
import './providers/book_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => BookListProvider(),
        ),

      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomeScreen(),
        initialRoute: '/home',
        routes: {
          '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
          BookDetailScreen.routeName: (context) => BookDetailScreen(),
        },
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
        },
        onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On home screen I have a tab where I sort out books based on category and after that I display a list of books that are trending. From anywhere user can tap a book image and view book details page where user can mark that book as favourites.

Home screen Image

[image: Home Screen Image]

Here is my book details page code

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../constants/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../providers/book_list_provider.dart';
import '../providers/book_provider.dart';

class BookDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = '/bookDetails';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bookId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final bookDetails = Provider.of<BookListProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getItemById(bookId);
    final bookItemProvider = Provider.of<BookItem>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                backgroundColor: kMainColor,
                expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        left: 25,
                        top: 35,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            } else {
                              print('I am hero');
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                  '/home', (route) => false);
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 32,
                            height: 32,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              color: kWhiteColor,
                            ),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/icons/icon_back_arrow.svg',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 25,
                        top: 35,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('User tapped the icon');
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 32,
                            height: 32,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              color: kWhiteColor,
                            ),
                            child: bookDetails.isFavourite
                                ? const Icon(Icons.favorite)
                                : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 62),
                            width: 170,
                            height: 225,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              child: Image.network(
                                bookDetails.imageUrl,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my BookItem Provider code

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

enum Categories {
  education,
  fiction,
  nonfiction,
}

class BookItem extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int amount;
  final int quantity;
  bool isFavourite = false;
  final String description;
  final String authorName;
  final Categories category;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int bookSold;
  BookItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.authorName,
    required this.amount,
    required this.description,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.category,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.bookSold,
  });

  void isFavouriteToggle() {
    isFavourite = !isFavourite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I have tried solutions from google but that doesn't worked. I am new in this so sorry if it is a silly question.

Comment: You can create a minimal sample snippet that will reproduce the same error, So that others can copy ->  paste your snippet. Also, there are parts like `BookListProvider` isn't define here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your book details page to :
class BookDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget

for that click on statelessWidget , the yellow led will show click the arrow and choose StatefulWidget

after that when the person click the button to change the book to favorite save as normal and add a

```
setState(() {
```

notice change the value also in the book detail page
//code
});

to show it in the screen

because statelessWidget is static and can't be change in the process but StatefulWidget can with setState

hope answering your question

Comment: But it will rebuild the whole widget, isn't it? I don't want that. I just want to rebuild that icon.

Comment: statelessWidget is static and can't be change in the process but StatefulWidget can with setState: https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w